# Jenkins change-assembly-version-plugin not updating AssemblyInfo.cs file in asp.net project

Tags: git, jenkins

We're working on migrating our builds to Jenkins.  I'm running a POC on an older ASP.NET project I just added a new MSTest project to.  I'm trying to version the output from the project through the use of the change-assembly-version-plugin.

The output from the build updates the AssemblyInfo.cs file from the new test project but it doesn't for the ASP.NET project even though the build logs state the file has been updated.

I've went as far as copying the AssemblyInfo.cs file from the test project and placing it in the ASP.NET project to ensure it's not something in the file that's causing the plugin to fail on save.  I've also copied and slimmed down the build so that all it's doing is pulling the source code and updating the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  I've also tried placing the AssemblyInfo.cs file in different directories to see if that could be and issue.  One last thing, the file is not set to read only.

[ChangeAssemblyVersionBuildStep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bne0l.jpg)

Build Logs

> Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectFolder\test
>
> [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
>
> [WS-CLEANUP] Done
>
> Cloning the remote Git repository
>
> Cloning repository http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git
>
> git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectFolder\test # timeout=10
>
> Fetching upstream changes from http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git
>
> git.exe --version # timeout=10
>
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> git.exe config remote.origin.url http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git # timeout=10
>
> git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>
> git.exe config remote.origin.url http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git # timeout=10
>
> Fetching upstream changes from http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git
>
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://MyServer/zjenkinspoc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> git.exe rev-parse "origin/Develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
>
> Checking out Revision hash (origin/Develop)
>
> git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>
> git.exe checkout -f hash
>
> git.exe rev-list hash # timeout=10
>
> Changing the file(s) **/AssemblyInfo.cs to version : 1.0.0.3
>
> Updating file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectFolder\test\MyProject.Tests\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs, Version : 1.0.0.3
>
> Updating file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectFolder\test\MyProject.Tests\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>
> Updating file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectFolder\test\MyProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs, Version : 1.0.0.3
>
> Updating file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectFolder\test\MyProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>
> Finished: SUCCESS

Output: Test project AssemblyInfo.cs file has this added to the end

> [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.3")]
>
> [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.3")]

ASP.NET project AssemblyInfo.cs file is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the file getting updated had the following two lines.  The file not getting updated did not. I added the lines to the second file and everything worked as it should.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```